# anaconda-navigator command not found

Tags: command-line, 20.04

I have installed successfully Anaconda 3 for Ubuntu 20.04. After installing it yesterday, Anaconda Navigator worked perfectly. The day after, I tried to open it on the terminal, it says:

```
command not found
```

Any advice?

Comment: Have you checked your paths? Please [edit] your question, showing the output of `echo $PATH` and also the path to the Navigator binary. Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/43030871/4424636, it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you followed anaconda documentation to install anaconda in the default path

you need to add the folder path of the extracted Anaconda in your system path, so that you can easily access its command tool without switching to its directory from anywhere in the terminal.

Execute the below commands from terminal

```
echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/youruserdirectory/anaconda3/bin">> ~/.bashrc
```

Close and open your terminal. Now the command anaconda-navigator should load it.

Answer (score 0):

run `export PATH=/home/yourUserName/anaconda3/bin:$PATH` in terminal. Replace yourUserName with your pc user name. After that run `anaconda-navigator` command.